# Hide approved edits in edit queue

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

In the edit queue the question already reviewed and approved / rejected gets hidden / collapsed. However when a post needs more votes for approval the post doesn't collapse, but instead a message is edit, e.g.: `This suggestion still needs 1 approval vote from other reviewers.`

Can these messages also be "hidden"? This way one doesn't have to scroll through the posts already voted on. I neither see the relevance of keeping those posts open, but maybe I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

The  developers are working on [a new review system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137174/new-feature-community-review-tasks) even as we speak; I suspect what you're asking for is part of that consideration. You may want to head over to the linked thread and join the conversation.

Comment: What happened to the witch kings? ;)

Comment: Hmmmm bit hard to check whether my post still is useful considering the fact that you need 2k to see anything. Bit strange.

Comment: I edited my post inside the "no edit history" window.

Comment: I know. Just sad I couldn't revert ;)